# Объясните пожалуйста про машинный эпсилон

Tags: c#, математика, точность

```
public static IList<double> Solve(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        const double eps = 0.00001;
        double discriminant = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);

        if (discriminant < -eps)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if ((discriminant >= -eps) && (discriminant <= eps))
        {
            double x = (-b) / (2 * a);
            return new[] { x };
        }
        else
        {
            double x1 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
            double x2 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
            return new[] { x1, x2 };
        }
    }
```

Вот стандартный метод решения квадратного уравнения, с учетом точности вычисления. Такой вопрос, допустим мы взяли уравнение с такими коэффициентами, в которых дискриминант получается очень очень маленьким, и входит в рамки точности, т.е. мы его воспринимаем как ноль, и получаем одно решение(правильное). Но допустим, мы умножили все коэффициенты уравнения на очень большое число, корни не должны меняться, но вот дискриминант тогда получается большим, и уже мы его воспринимаем как >0. Но это не правильно получается. Как мне в таком случае рассчитывать эпсилон? Мне подсказали что тут нужен машинный эпсилон, я почитал, но не особо понял. Может кто-нибудь помощь в данной ситуации, как рассчитывать точность, если мне просто даны коэффициенты a,b,c?

Comment: else if ((discriminant >= -eps) && (discriminant <= eps)) - вот тут что-то не то

Comment: Попробуйте последние 2 условия поменять местами
1 `if (discriminant < -eps)...`
2 `else if (discriminant > eps)...`
3 `else...`
Тогда 3 условие будет выполняться при discriminant∈[-0.00001,0.00001];

Comment: Многое зависит от поставленной задачи и требований к решению, которые знаете только вы, ваш вопрос - [XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567).

Comment: Если хотите использовать машинную точность, то никакие эпсилоны здесь не нужны, будет использоваться приведение точности double, и всё. Пусть вызывающий метод читает разность корней, и если оно меньше допустимого, то считает что это один корень.

Comment: @aepot имеется ввиду, как решить проблему, если два уравнения должны давать один корень, но второе уравнение дает два, так как у него коэффициенты умножены на некоторое большое число, а значит и дискриминант увеличился. А так как он увеличился, то с заданной точностью я не проверю того, что он по идее должен быть нулем.

Comment: Если получаете 2 корня, значит их действительно два, верно? Иначе можно считать формулу их вычисления неверной. Ну или влияет погрешность при вычислениях. Но вы пытаетесь вылечить проблему погрешности делая ее еще более грубой за счет введения точности, а должно быть всё наоборот.

Comment: @aepot например. a =  -0.5882352941176471  b = +3.5294117647058822  c = -5.294117647058823. Вот если с этими коэффициентами решать, то по идее корень один. Но если каждый коэффициент умножить на 1000000000.0, то уже будет два корня, а такого быть не должно. И вот как проверку что ли делать ?

Comment: 2 корня появляются как раз из-за погрешности. Можете добавить анализ кэффициентов и выполнять нормализацию разделяя или умножая коэффициенты на число, чтобы вычисления не втыкались в точность double. Либо использовать длинную арифметику.

Comment: @aepot вот именно, из за погрешности. Мне подсказали что нужно в этом случае использовать как то машинный эпсилон, вычисляя его и умножая на масштаб что ли. Но я не понял зачем и для чего? Да и как я масштаб должен найти, если заданы только коэффициенты?

Comment: Ну это например поделить все коэффициенты на b, а b станет равным единице.

Comment: @aepot это так масштаб получается найти?

Comment: Сначала попробуйте